# How to use grep or grepl in order to identify variables?

Tags: r, grepl

good afternoon. Here is the situation:

I have a variable called "dep" that is defined as:

```r
dep <- c("txn_amt", "txn_cnt", "acct_cnt")
```

I defined fn_form as:

```
fn_form = c(dep, paste("log(",dep,"+1)",sep=""),paste("log(",dep,")",sep=""))
```

When I ran:

```
fnform <- "count"
  if(length(grep("log",fn_form))>0) {
   fnform <- "log"
 }
   if(grepl("log\\(\\+1\\)",fn_form)>0) {
  fnform <- "log+1"
 }
```

it is not saving "count", "log" and "log+1". It is only saving "count" and "log" because R is not recognizing the difference between log and log+1. How can I fix this in order to save for these 3 values?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Do you really mean to use `length(grep)` in the first conditional and `grepl` (with an L, no call to `length)  in the second one?

Answer (score 1):

There were a couple of problems.  First, you're trying to evaluate all elements of `fn_form`, but then replace `fn_form` with a single value.  More to the point you were raising though, is that you were searching for "log(+1)", when you should have been searching for "log(.*+1)" - because the variable name is inside the parentheses attached to log.  Here's how I would do it:

```r
dep <- c("txn_amt", "txn_cnt", "acct_cnt")
fn_form = c(dep, paste("log(",dep,"+1)",sep=""),paste("log(",dep,")",sep=""))

sapply(fn_form, function(x){
  out <- "count"
  if(grepl("log\\(", x))out <- "log"
  if(grepl("log\\(.*\\+1", x))out <- "log+1"
  out
})
#>         txn_amt         txn_cnt        acct_cnt  log(txn_amt+1)  log(txn_cnt+1) 
#>         "count"         "count"         "count"         "log+1"         "log+1" 
#> log(acct_cnt+1)    log(txn_amt)    log(txn_cnt)   log(acct_cnt) 
#>         "log+1"           "log"           "log"           "log"
```

<sup>Created on 2023-06-01 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Absolutely genius! Thanks a lot! It worked